# Migrate table from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Migrate a table from Oracle to SQL Server.

I have used Toad to export (select * from table) into a pipe delimited .txt file so it can be used to be consumed in SQL Server. Now the Oracle table has a DATE column and the output from Toad for that column is (2/26/2016 3.05.10.000000 PM). This format is not being compatible for the datetime column in SQL Server side.

I feel we can convert the date in Oracle to a compatible SQL Server format for easier ingestion.

Please help me understand the conversion both from Oracle to a compatible SQL Server format.

Comment: use to_date() to convert to mssql datetime

Comment: Thanks for your response. The to_date() fnc is returning format like 26/2/2016, however I am worried the precision upto milliseconds is not showing and will be lost in the export.

Answer (score 1):

Create Oracle Linked server in SQL Server with ODBC connection. and use that Linked server to play with Oracle and SQL Server tables using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You must understand that DATE datatypes are *binary* data.  Using to_date() on a column that is already a DATE is inappropriate. It forces oracle to perform (behind the scenes) a to_char() on the DATE column in order to produce character data that is the required input to to_date().  Then, when you see (in your text csv file) that it has produced a "date" in some particular format, it is because oracle has then had to run the result of your to_date() back through to_char(), using the default NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting to produce a character string for the text output.

So your solution is this:
First, determine what text format of a date MSSQL wants when it uses this csv file.  I don't know what that is, but for the sake of argument, let's say it is 'yyyy-mm-dd'. With that information, construct your SELECT in oracle like this:

```
select mycol1,
       to_char(my_date_col,'yyyy-mm-dd'),
       mycol2
from my_table;
```

That said, I agree with the others, why bother with this cumbersome process in the first place?  Or even some other intermediary like SSIS?  Why not just create a shared server in MSSQL and query the oracle table directly?  Or create a database link in the Oracle DB and, using the oracle transparent gateway as the conduit, INSERT directly into the MSSQL table from Oracle?  Either the linked server or the database link will be much faster than any external process.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a best way to transfer Oracle table to SQL Serveris by using SSIS package.

> You can have a Source as Oracle and your conversion issue can be fixed by Data 
>   Conversion task and your Destination can be SQL Server.

Comment: So there is no way to prevent data loss, other than using migration utilities? I still think there got to be a way to preserve the date format in milliseconds in Oracle and still be able to load into Sql server.

Comment: Set up a DB link.  Then you can transfer the data directly with no export/import necessary.